# IIS Basic Authentication for ashx files

Tags: basic-authentication, ashx

I need to make the authentication method of my ashx files to Basic Authentication. I set the applications authentication method as Basic Authentication. All files on the application asks for user name and password except ashx files.

I read a lot on Google and Stack Overflow but had no proper answer which works. How can I add .ashx files to the list??

Thanks in advance
telmessos